# How do you return a complete url with get_success_url(self) in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How do you return a url using get_success_url(self) in django without using `reverse` for a generic view? Basically, I want to have something as below.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    url = self.object.url # This is a charfield with "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
    return url
```

I know that people often use `reverse` when returning a url, but I would like do it like above. Thank you, and please write any questions you have. By the way, I never tested the above code, but I don't know if it will work properly.

Comment: Do you storing url inside your object?

Comment: Yes, in `self.object.url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"reverse(..)"  is part of the django logic to store the url structure in urlpatterns in ONE place and then in the whole code refere to it in the moment of the request being executed via the name. If you do not want to follow that logic - feel free to store anything you like in your "object.url" and return it like you propose. You then just do not follow the django urlpattern idea. Up to you to decide if that is important or "right" in your case.

If the url targets outside our own server space, reverse is anyway not usefull as those urls are not part of your urlpattens.

Comment: So, you are saying that the code I wrote in the question works, right? So, there is no problem in copying a link from another website into a Charfield in my model(self.object.url), and then just returning it like I wrote in the question.

Comment: if you point to another website it is not possible to use reverse() - so yes in that case the hard coded url is the only way.